# need to show first three letters of basketball followed by dots

Tags: javascript, html, css

- i am new to css.
- i am having a great trouble with flex property.
- when its bigger size its working fine.
- but when I reduce to the screen size of **320px I am having problem**...
- I need to show first three letters of basketball followed by dots.
- so it should be like Bas...
- I tried giving the below properties but nothing is working fine..
- can you guys tell me how to fix it... there is problem with flex.
- providing my code below and fiddle

```or-tag-here
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

  .sports-title {
      border: 1px solid red !important;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 1 !important;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      display: -webkit-box !important;
      padding-left: 0px !important;
      width: 81px !important;
      flex-grow: 0 !important;
      flex-shrink: 0 !important;
      flex-basis: 0px !important;
      /* display: inline !important; */
      /* flex: 0 !important; */
      /* width: 77px !important; */
  }

}
```

Comment: Try :  text-overflow: ellipsis;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` instead of `flex`, use `max-width` instead of `width` and add `text-overflow: ellipsis`

```css
.sports {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 73px;
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 24px 60px 21px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.sports-leftBlock {
  background: transparent url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg) top left no-repeat !important;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
  width: 55px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px !important;
  top: 25px !important;
}

.sports-leftBlock,
.sports-rightBlock {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.sports-title {
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.sports-title {
  font-family: 'Mercury Display', Times, serif;
  font-size: 40px !important;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  left: 108px;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 136px;
  color: #12395B !important;
}

.sports-title {
  padding-left: 50px !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.sports-rightBlock {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .sports-title {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 1 !important;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    max-width: 100px !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    /* display: inline !important; */
    /* flex: 0 !important; */
    /* width: 77px !important; */
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sports-leftBlock {
    /* border: 1px solid black; */
    width: 63px;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sports">

  <div class="sports-leftBlock">
  </div>

  <h1 class="sports-title">
    basketball football swimming 
  </h1>

  <div class="sports-rightBlock">
    <button type="button" class="sports-close">
      <span class="screenReader">Close Pop-up Dialog</span>
      <span class="sports-closeIcon">
        <span class="sports-closeIcon-icon"></span>
      <span class="sports-closeIcon-highContrastGlyph" aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </span>
      <span class="keyboardFocusRing"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: it worked but can you give some explanation so that next time I can fix it myself :(

Comment: @texirv look at the top of my post... is that unclear?

Comment: one more thing at 320px text is overlapping icon...that should not happen too...I tested your code in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ezprksv1/4/

Comment: @texirv change the `padding-left` in your `@media` query. https://jsfiddle.net/ezprksv1/6/ And in the future, don't ask for new solutions in the comments - keep the details of the post clear in your OP and try not to "move the goalpost" with new things after folks have already answered. If you have a new problem or something you forgot, just make a new post.

Comment: is it possible to h1, not overlap since right now border is overlapping I need the border too....can you give little explanation since it will be helpful...in your top answer you just asked me to change the properties

Comment: @texirv https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow that enables the ellipses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space that keeps the text on a single line instead of breaking to multiple lines when the page width shrinks. I don't know why I had to use `max-width` instead of `width`, I just trial-and-errored and it worked. Also be sure to accept an answer as a solution if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what you were trying to accomplish. I apologize for my first solution not incorporating that, however, it was not specified in your original question. The error was fixed by setting the `position:relative;` and changing some other code. The code under the title under the @media selector now looks like this:

```
  .sports-title {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
      max-width:100px;
      position:relative;
      left: 5px;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: you should delete your other answer, or delete this one and update the old answer with the contents of this one.

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot to do that oops!

Comment: @MickeyB can you give some explanation it will help in understanding :(